# Angular Directive cannot manipulate DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive for a "Tile" widget.

Problem: I cannot manipulate the rendered DOM elements. I have tried: compile(), controller(), pre-link(), and post-link(). Instead of seeing fully rendered DOM elements, the "Ng-If" turns into comments. I want the content of those "Ng-If"'s.

The only working inelegant solution I know is to place my code within a $timeout(...), but I fear it will cause asynchronous issues, especially with 100+ tiles created.

Is there a more elegant solution?

**index.html**:

```
<div metro-tile json-layout-data="t" ng-repeat="t in tileData"></div>
```

**template.html**:

```
<div>
    <a ng-if="mode == '1x1'">...</a>
    <a ng-if="mode != '1x1'">...</a>
</div>
```

**directive.js**:

```
angular.module('...').directive('...',
['$log', '$timeout', blah, blah,
    function ($log, $timeout, blah, blah) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                jsonContent: '=jsonContent'
            },
            templateUrl: "tpl/metro-tile.tpl.html",
            replace: true,
            controller: function( $scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude ) {
                $log.log("controller " + $element);
            },
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                $log.log("compile " + tElement);
                return {
                    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                        $log.log("prelink " + scope + " " + iElement);
                    },
                    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                        $log.log("postlink " + scope + " " + iElement);

                        //$timeout(function() {
                        //  $log.log(iElement.children());
                        //});
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: How about using ng-show/ng-hide instead of ng-if? ng-if will not render those elements in the DOM unless the value is truthy where as ng-show/ng-hide will still render the elements in the DOM but will show/hide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to keep the $timeout solution since its only penalty is running the code on the next digest cycle.